# StringTokenizer split at "<br/>"

Tags: java

Maybe I am stupid but I don't understand why the behaviour of StringTokenizer here:

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml;

String object = (String) value;
String escaped = escapeHtml(object);
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(escaped, escapeHtml("<br/>"));
```

If fx. value is

```
Hej<br/>$user.get(0).name Har vundet<br/><table border='1'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Played</th><th>Brewed</th></tr>#foreach( $u in $user )<tr><td>$u.name</td> <td>$u.played</td> <td>$u.brewed</td></tr>#end</table><br/>
```

Then the result is

```
Hej
$use
.
e
(0).name Ha
 vunde
a
e 
o
de
='1'
h
Name
h
h
P
ayed
h
h
B
ewed
h
#fo
each( $u in $use
 )
d
$u.name
d

d
$u.p
ayed
d

d
$u.
ewed
d
#end
a
e
```

It makes no sense to me.

How can I make it behave as I expect to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> The characters in the delim argument are the delimiters for separating tokens.
>   Delimiter characters themselves will not be treated as tokens.

In other words, the characters that tell `StringTokenizer` when to separate the string are:

- <
- b
- r
- /
- >

When it matches any of those characters in the string (the variable `escaped` in your code), the `StringTokenizer` instance will split the result and drop the token. You can confirm this by noting that the letter `r` does not occur in the output.

Use [`String.split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), instead, as others suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Each character in the string is considered a token for splitting on. So your code splits on each "&", "l", "t", ";", "b", "r", "/" or "g" character (since `escapeHtml` will replace the "<" and ">" with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively).

You probably want to use `String.split` which takes a regular expression as the thing to split on:

```
String[] parts = object.split("<br/>");
```

or

```
String[] parts = escaped.split(escapeHtml("<br/>"));
```

Just make sure that there are no regex special characters in your split token.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to divide a string / text by a word and not only by few characters then you better use `String.split`

I've done the test:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "Hej<br/>$user.get(0).name Har vundet<br/><table border='1'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Played</th><th>Brewed</th></tr>#foreach( $u in $user )<tr><td>$u.name</td> <td>$u.played</td> <td>$u.brewed</td></tr>#end</table><br/>";
    String[] lines = s.split("<br/>");
    for(String ss:lines)
        System.out.println(ss);
}
```

and here you have the result:

```
Hej
$user.get(0).name Har vundet
<table border='1'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Played</th><th>Brewed</th></tr>#foreach( $u in $user )<tr><td>$u.name</td> <td>$u.played</td> <td>$u.brewed</td></tr>#end</table>
```

Tjena

Answer (score 0):

StringTokenizer splits using each character.

You need to use split. (be careful though as it takes a regular expression)

```
String[] lines = "some html string<br/>with line breaks<br/>".split("<br/>")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use StringTokenizer with a multicharacter delimiter. One possible solution to your problem is to replace `"<br>"` with a character that you can guarantee will not appear in your string, and then us StringTokenizer with that character as the delimiter.